# Why this change in the Infinity Stone gauntlet?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

Thanos's infinity stone gauntlet is left-handed. The one that the Avengers make in Endgame is right-handed. Is there a significant or symbolic reason for this?

I'm interested in in-universe or out-of-universe answers. And I completely understand the answer might simply be random or even unconscious decision making by the film-makers. I just found it curious and wondered if there's anywhere that it is mentioned.

Comment: Thanos was left-handed?  :P

Comment: Lol that possibility crossed my mind too.

Comment: Because the right-hand gauntlet was really the fake one?

Comment: I believe Thanos knew what would happen to the hand once he snapped. A warrior would rather sacrifice his left hand and not right, if he were right handed?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the scene where Hela is next to the (fake) infinity gauntlet in Odin's vault, you'll see that the gauntlet is right handed.

[image: Hela next to the fake gauntlet]

The hand the gauntlet is worn on is insignificant IMO. Tony is right handed so it could have been a natural/subconscious decision for him to put the stones on his right hand.

It's likely personal preference, as [A J♦](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100193/why-this-change-in-the-infinity-stone-gauntlet/100196#comment169742_100193) pointed out, Thanos could have preferred a left handed gauntlet.

Another reason could be that [the dwarves](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dwarves_of_Nidavellir) made it left handed because it was the only mould they had. It could have also been the only mould left after they made Odin's right handed gauntlet.

Either way, Tony, Bruce and Thanos were the most powerful beings in the universe when they had the gauntlet, I doubt they cared about which hand it was on.

Comment: Thanos definitely wields his Darth Maul sword with his right hand. Seems more like he put the large and bulky gauntlet on his non-dominant  hand.

Comment: Similar to how you should wear a watch on your non dominant hand/wrist/arm.

Answer (score -2):

Marvel movies have been playing at Tony's left arm constantly getting hurt. Pretty much every movie in phase 3 has it written in the script along with him babying it. The gauntlet is obviously mostly his design, I'd like to think he wanted it to be right handed just in case he had to use it himself. I've only seen Endgame once but they don't seem to reference his left arm in his last movie at all. (unless i'm right about the right handed gauntlet)

Also most people (Avengers) are right handed...